# Cannot connect to XAMPP localhost from android device over WiFi

Tags: android, xampp, localhost, wifi, server

I installed XAMPP apache and mysql server on my laptop and I can view my server at localhost in my laptop's mozilla firefox browser. What I want to do is access my server from my android phone. My android phone and my laptop are both connected to the same WiFi access point. I looked up my laptop's IP address using ipconfig and typed it in my phone's chrome browser: 192.168.0.14:80 to open the server page on my phone. It didn't. I looked up on the internet and found various hacks, none of which worked for me.

```
> Turned off my firewall; no luck.

> Modified the httpd.conf file to listen on different port numbers
  and IP addresses but none worked.  

> Created a new firewall rule to listen on different ports, using 
  which didn't work.

> Turned off my anti virus. Still nothing.
```

It works on the android emulator just fine.

What is wrong with it? Any help would be appreciated.

```
**UPDATE:**
I tried using a public network and it asked me to change configuration 
to allow public networks. I removed the restriction in the 
httpd-xampp.conf file and I was able to connect to my server from my 
android phone.

But I still cannot connect using my local WiFi network.
```

Comment: did you try turning off the firewall?

Comment: Yes. I even added a new rule for listening on port number 80, 8080 but still cannot connect. I also disabled my Avast antivirus.